# Combining two strings in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, logic, c-strings

I've just started learning about arrays and strings and I wanted to join the inputs of two strings, `stringA` and `stringB` and put their values in another string, `stringC`, after finding their lengths.

I want to solve it without built-in functions.

I've tried writing the code but I'm getting an error in the length of `stringB` and also the contents of `stringC`. Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    char stringA[100];
    char stringB[100];
    char stringC[100];
    int lengthA=0;
    int lengthB=0;
    int i,j;

    printf("Enter a string A, terminate with a tilde.\n");
    scanf("%[^~]",stringA);
    while (stringA[lengthA] != '\0') 
        lengthA++;
    printf("The length is %d\n",lengthA+1);
    printf("Enter a string B, terminate with a !.\n");
    scanf("%[^!]",stringB);
    lengthB=0;
    while (stringB[lengthB] != '\0') 
        lengthB++;
    printf("The length is %d\n",lengthB+1);
    for(i=0;i<lengthA;i++)
        stringC[i]=stringA[i];
    for(i=lengthA;i<lengthA+lengthB;i++)
        stringC[i]=stringB[i];
    printf("%s",stringC);
    return 0;
}
```

Your help is appreciated!

Comment: why not use `strcat(destinationString,sourceString)` from `string.h` ?

Comment: Yes, I could do that, but I have to do it without in-built functions.

Comment: that explains it. keep it up!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're leaving the tilde and newline in after you import the first string. Since you're clearing a certain number of characters, you could just call `getchar()` a certain number of times, but there might be a more elegant way to do it.

In your loop where you're setting `stringC`, you're also indexing into `stringB` improperly.

Make sure you null terminate `stringC`, although I don't think it'll break this specific code. It's good practice.

Finally, you're outputting an extra +1 on the string lengths. That's not necessary (unless you're trying to count the ~ and ! as part of the length).

Comment: Aren't we supposed to count the null terminator in the length? That's why I added 1.

Comment: No, null terminators are generally not included in the length. `strlen()`, for instance, returns the index of the null terminator, i.e. the length of the string not counting the null terminator.

Answer (score 3):

Everything looks good up to this loop:

```
for(i=lengthA;i<lengthA+lengthB;i++)
    stringC[i]=stringB[i];
```

Here, you need to think about the index into `stringB`.

Also, don't forget about the NUL terminator.

**edit**: Also, don't forget that when you're reading `stringB`, the tilde and the newline are still on the input buffer.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean by "the index into stringB"?

Comment: @Shail All strings start at index `0`

Answer (score 0):

You ae counting from 0 in `lengthA` and you increment for every character until '\0', so lengthA is your actual length of string . You dont need lengthA+1

maybe appending a null character at the end of stringC will help?

Answer (score 0):

In this loop, you will have to eliminate the offset of `lengthA` for `StringB` as shown

```
for(i=lengthA;i<lengthA+lengthB;i++)
    stringC[i]=stringB[(i - lengthA)];
```

And add a `NULL` terminator after the loop as

```
stringC[i] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

Jacob has point.

So, to fix your existing code:

```
char stringC[200];
```

And also, your indexes for stringB are wrong. This should work:

```
stringC[i]=stringB[i-lengthA];
```

Answer (score 0):

The index of `stringB` in the second loop is the problem. Remember that the index `i` is the `lengthA` at this point. Maybe you forgot to use your variable `j` ;-)

```
for(i=lengthA, j = 0; i < lengthA+lengthB; i++, j++)
    stringC[i] = stringB[j];

stringC[i + 1] = '\0';
```

As a hint: you dont need `j`:

```
for(i=lengthA; i < lengthA+lengthB; i++)
    stringC[i] = stringB[i - lengthA];

stringC[i + 1] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 0):

The following question talks about input buffer which is not getting cleared in the above code.
[How to clear input buffer in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7898215/how-to-clear-input-buffer-in-c)
Try using a debugger and check the contents of stringB after the second scanf statement.